# Expression 'application' cannot be invoked as a function

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Kotlin application with kotlin-dsl gradle files. I'd like to set `mainClassName` to be able to use `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`.

I'd like use the application for this and I gradle cannot resolve it even if I have `application` plugin applied.

Kotlin version: 1.6.10

[image]

After a lot of research it looks like I'm the only one who doesn't have application in the gradle file.

Comment: Please provide your code as a code block, not as an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `application` to your plugins list like

```
plugins {
    ...
    application
}
```